# Finding the real irrational root of a cubic polynomial?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, cubics

I just wanted to check if anyone can see a simpler way to solve this. Because I am not looking forward to using the cubic formula to solve it!
$$ det(\lambda-AI) = \left| \begin{array}{ccc}
\lambda + a & -b & -b  \\
c & \lambda + d & 0 \\
0 & d & \lambda \end{array} \right| = 0$$

requires us to solve

$$ \lambda^3 + (a+d)\lambda^2 + (ad+bc)\lambda -bcd = 0 $$

(I can find no rational roots. As, by the rational zero theorem, the rational roots would be $\pm$ a factor of bcd. The only factors which will cancel out bcd are $\lambda = \pm\sqrt{bc}$ or $\lambda = -d$ neither of which result in $ det(\lambda-AI) = 0$.)

Is the next step the cubic formula? :(

Comment: Are you sure the signs in the matrix are correct? If the determinant were **either** $\lambda^3 + (a+d)\lambda^2 + (ad + bc)\lambda + bcd$ **or** $\lambda^3 + (a+d)\lambda^2 + (ad - bc)\lambda - bcd$, then $\lambda = -d$ would be a solution.

Comment: I know! It's sooo infuriating, but i've been over the signs several times... This is what happens when you build your own model rather than doing beautiful bookwork

Comment: I do not see the relevance of the Rational Roots Theorem. For relevance one would need the cubic to have integer coefficients. And depending on the values of $b,c,d$ the number $bcd$ may have many integer factors other than the obvious ones,

Comment: So the original matrix you have is really
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} -a & b & b\\ -c & -d & 0\\ 0 & -d & 0 \end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Oh I see, interesting point. But I'm hoping to do a theoretical rather than numerical description, so the only factors of bcd are indeed b,c,d.

Comment: No it is  $$ A = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
-a & -b & -b \\
c & -d & 0 \\
0 & d & 0 \\ \end{array} \right) $$

Comment: Then you forgot to switch signs outside of the main diagonal.

Comment: Oh sweet!!! Thank you so much Pedro!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify for those who may see this question in the future, the actual matrix was

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} -a & -b & -b\\ c & -d & 0\\ 0 & d & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

so that the polynomial to solve was $$\lambda^3 + (a+d)\lambda^2 + (ad + bc)\lambda + bcd,$$

which has an obvious root $\lambda = -d$, and hence factors out.